# backbone.js - mouseover kills events on views

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, mouseover

This is a simple todo app that currently only lists a few li views within a ul collection view. I am trying to cause the click event to fire a simple showAlert function

If I keep my mouse over one of the task views(li) and refresh the page so that my mouse ends up hovering over that specific li once reloaded, the click event will fire off my showAlert function.

The problem is once I move my mouse(most likely triggering a mouseover event), I lose the click event on all task views(li) including the view I was initially hovering over.

Based on all posts I could find closely related to this problem, I've tried using this.delegateEvents() in various places, with no luck.

**Preceding code**

```
(function() {

  window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {}
  };

  window.template = function(id) {
    return _.template( $('#' + id).html() );
  };

  App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  App.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Task
  });

  App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function() {
      this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
      return this;
    },

    addOne: function(task) {
      var taskView = new App.Views.Task({ model: task });
      this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
    }
  });
```

**This is the view in question**

```
  App.Views.Task = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    events: {
      'click': 'showAlert'
    },

    showAlert: function() {
      alert('yes!');
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html( this.model.get('title') );
      return this;
    }
  });
```

**proceeding code**

```
  var tasksCollection = new App.Collections.Tasks([
    {
      title: 'Task 1',
      priority: 3
    },
    {
      title: 'Task 2',
      priority: 4
    },
    {
      title: 'Task 3',
      priority: 5
    }
  ]);

  var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks({ collection: tasksCollection });
  $('.tasks').html(tasksView.render().el);

})();
```

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsbin.com/fujimiri/1/

Comment: thanks Jack, I linked my Backbone script src to the src you listed at http://jashkenas.github.io/backbone/backbone-min.js, it worked and then I reverted back to my local Development version and it's working? Very strange but thank you

Comment: No problem, since it seems like the problem can't be reproduced I'm going to vote to close.